# ng-repeat array with different size properties and then use that to style each div uniquely

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an array of 50 squares, each with different side lengths that are being randomly generated and I'm attempting to ng-repeat through the array and use the side length to style each one uniquely. Any thoughts?

```
<div ng-controller="ShapesController as sc" ng-init="sc.displaySorted()">
  <div class="square" ng-repeat="sq in sc.shapesToDisplaySq" style="width:" + sq.sideLength + "px" + ";height:" + sq.sideLength + "px" + ";">
    {{sq}}
  </div>
</div>
```

The shapesToDisplay array does console log an array of objects, each with a unique sideLength value, so I just need to find a way to translate that value to a css styling. Thanks!

[Console screenshot of square objects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bn7Gt.png) [DOM screenshot of {{sq}}](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1BFwV.png)

Comment: Is the 'shapesToDisplay array' equivalent to 'sc.shapesToDisplaySq'? Also can you post what the sq object look like?

Comment: use `ng-style` instead : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle

Comment: Yes! sc.shapesToDisplaySq is set to vm.shapestoDisplaySq, which logs out 50 square objects with a unique sideLength property. I'll add a photo of the console.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! when I try that it doesn't seem to be working and when I inspect it, it gives me an invalid property value. [Inspector screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YA3I3.png).

Here's my code now:

```
<div ng-controller="ShapesController as sc" ng-init="sc.displaySorted()">
  <div class="square" ng-repeat="sq in sc.shapesToDisplaySq" style="width: {{sq.sideLength}}; length: {{sq.sideLength}}">
    {{sq}}
  </div>

</div>
```

I also tried to add !important: [!important screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lb6NC.png)

Comment: Try this:

width: {{sq.sideLength}}px; height: {{sq.sideLength}}px

Comment: There is no length property in CSS you need to use height and you were missing unit (px) after value

Comment: OMG! That did it. Thanks! I changed it so many times, I was screwing up the simple stuff.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help.

Answer (score -1):

you need to use {{}} for the style

```
<div ng-controller="ShapesController as sc" ng-init="sc.displaySorted()">
  <div class="square" ng-repeat="sq in sc.shapesToDisplaySq" style="width: {{sq.sideLength}}px; length: {{sq.sideLength}}px">
    {{sq}}
  </div>

</div>
```